# ViewFlipper with a variable number of liniar layout

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout, viewflipper

In my app I need to use ViewFlipper for Switching screens by dragging over the touch screen. I have a ListView that contains some items. When a item is select I must to display some images. The problem is that the number of images is different from one item to another. So I think that I must create the LinearLayout and the ImageView programatically. Is it possible what I am tring to do?

Thanks in advance..

Here is the code I tried :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main">

    <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    </ViewFlipper>

</LinearLayout>
```

and on Oncreate() method :

```
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            LinearLayout l=new LinearLayout(this);
            l.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            l.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
            img.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            //ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo1);
            Drawable image1 = ImageOperations(getBaseContext(), url[i]);
            img.setImageDrawable(image1);

            l.addView(img);
        }
```

but nothing happens. I see only a big black screen.

Comment: are you adding the linearlayout to the viewflipper? That part is not seen in the code

Comment: This was the problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I exactly didnt understand what you saying but i worked on ViewFlipper before. There am using Four linear layouts as childviews for ViewFlipper which in xml. (where as firstly i tried to add listviews direclly as childviews but adding linearlayouts will make easier)

and added listviews,imageviews like you said to corresponding linearlayouts from java code.

and it worked .

Hope it helps.

Here my code i used for xml :

```
<RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tabrelay"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"

                >      

    <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/details" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        style="@style/FlipperMargins.flipper"
        >     


    <LinearLayout  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:listSelector="@color/sprgreen"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/deckbackn"
    style="@style/Webview.view"

    />
     <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="@dimen/webViewWidth" 
    android:layout_height="@dimen/webViewHeight"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:divider="@color/grey46"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:id="@+id/list2"
    android:background="@drawable/white"
    style="@style/Webview.view"

    />
     <LinearLayout  
    android:layout_width="@dimen/webViewWidth" 
    android:layout_height="@dimen/webViewHeight"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/list3"
    android:listSelector="@color/sprgreen"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/commentsbg"
    style="@style/Webview.view"

    />

   <WebView 
   android:id="@+id/helloWebView" 
   android:layout_width="@dimen/webViewWidth" 
   android:layout_height="@dimen/webViewHeight"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:background="@drawable/white"
   style="@style/Webview.view"
   /> 
   </ViewFlipper>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

after that you can get Ids of linearlayouts from xml and add whaterver you want listviews etc from java..,,

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I resolved the problem by adding the LinearLayout create by code to the ViewFlipper.

Comment: If you reslove your problem accept the right answer that helped you